# View failing on website after aditing in pgadmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have a schema in pgadmin in which i created three new tables to replace three old tables. Now my website wont show the layers regarding the edit anymore.
I made some edits to the new tables, which were fine. It did not return any problems. I deleted the three old tables and the old view. I then created a new view which and inserted the code from the old view. I updated the code by simply replacing all the old table names with the new ones in Atom.
Nothing is wrong with the code for the view. I ran it and it works just fine.

I also ran:

```
GRANT SELECT ON cup_dagtilbud.cup_dagtilbud_view
 TO sandkasse;
```

...because i thought something was wrong with the privileges. This also returned succesfull.

I looked through the files (on my computer) that make up the layer that are broken now and none of the refer to the view.
Can someone tell me if this is something i can fix in pgAdmin or if it is more likely that the problem is elsewhere?